# powershell send-mailmessage error - helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname

Tags: email, powershell, smtp

I've read many sources regarding this issue, but no luck :/

I am trying to use Powershell 4.0 (Windows server 2012 R2) to send e-mails via the Send-MailMessage commandlet in this way:

```
$From = "testuser@mydomain.cz"
$To = "somebody@mydomain.cz"
$Subject = "e-mail odeslany z powershellu :)"
$Body = "..."
$SMTPServer = "smtp.mydomain.cz"
$SMTPPort = "587"

$credentials = new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential “testuser@mydomain.cz”, (“xxxpasswordxxx” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $credentials -Verbose
```

The problem is that it ends up with the following error:

```
Send-MailMessage : Command parameter not implemented. The server response was: 5.5.2 <mydamnserver>: Helo command rejected:
 need fully-qualified hostname
At D:\sendmail.ps1:14 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Please, how can I satisfy the commandlet with FQ hostname? I do not want to change DNS or something, I just need to make the script "fake" the FQ hostnamein order to get rid of the error... How can I do that, please?

I've found that there is a **"clientDomain" attribute of the "network" element which needs to be changed** - but how? I've never written anything in .NET :/

Thanks a lot

Comment: see the attribute docs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164242.aspx

Answer (score 0):

OK, it just works now. I do not understand much why, but here is a hint:

The original error message (*"The server response was: 5.5.2 : Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname﻿"*) occurs now when I intentionally put a wrong password. So it might be I had been using a wrong password before.

Strange is that when I had been looking to mailserver logs, I found no "testuser" lines... Weird.

Anyway, let's consider this closed.